# Meteor collection find sort after filtering

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor

I've a collection of addresses, I would like to filter the collection to keep the 10 nearest address, then I would like to be able to sort them from the farther to the nearest.

Is that possible to achieve this within a single find request in meteor ?

The following gives me the 10 nearest addresses:

`Addresses.find({}, {sort:{distance:1}, limit:10})`;

but they are ordered by increasing distance, obviously if I do set `distance:-1` they will come by decreasing order but I will also get only the 10 farthest addresses…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `fetch` the result of your search and `reverse` it it should work.

`Addresses.find({}, {sort:{distance:1}, limit:10}).fetch().reverse()`

The only drawback is that now it's an array and not a cursor anymore

Comment: This is what I eventually did, a way to keep a cursor on the data would have been to create an anonymous collection in between then use the observe pattern to populate it with the filtered set. Then at last, to sort the filtered anonymous collection. But in this case it's an overkill…

Answer (score 1):

You need the aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  { $sort: { distance: 1 } },
  { $limit: 10 },
  { $sort: { distance: -1 } }
)
```

I hope the query is self-explanatory.

If you can't run an `aggregation` or native mongo query in `MeteorJS`, then you'll probably have to reverse the results you got from the DB query programatically.

Comment: Your answer is correct within a MongoDB context, but for now `findAndModify, aggregate functions, and map/reduce aren't supported.` [as in the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)

Comment: Edited for your perusal.